# is there any suggestions on add rows and columns in datagridview in vb

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

This is may code so far

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button1.Click
    Dim tab As Integer = TextBox1.Text
    Dim row As Integer = TextBox2.Text
    Dim i, j As Integer
    DataGridView1.ColumnCount = tab
    Dim q As Integer = 0
    For i = 1 To tab
        DataGridView1.Columns(q).Name = ""
        For j = 1 To row
              DataGridView1.Rows().Add({i & "x" & j & "=" & (i * j)})
              
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

the output i get was like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yilA2.png)

Comment: Could you update your question with an actual question?  What is the exact issue you facing and a clear explanation of how this differs from expectations

Comment: how can i add a  multiplication tables of 1 to given number and given number of rows in datagridview in vb ?

Comment: No one should need to read the comments to understand the question. You were asked to update your question, not add a comment. Edit the question and provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, as you should have in the first place. That includes an explanation of EXACTLY what you're trying to achieve, how you're trying to achieve it and what happens when you try.

Comment: Sorry but even after your updates it's kind of hard to understand exactly what you're asking.  If I had to guess I would suggest you read up on Data Binding techniques

Answer (score 0):

the question is not clear, but from what I read in the comment you should be asking how to add the 1x1 to 1x4 in the datagridview. If so then you only need to scroll up to see it or  try enlarging your datagridview, sorry if i interpret wrongly.